# Why is putting an inline variable assignment before a subshell a syntax error?

Tags: bash

Something I've come across a few times recently: how to set a variable and execute commands *using* that variable in a one-liner? I often want to do this when I have one string which needs to be embedded in a long list of commands in multiple places:

The most obvious approach is this (contrived example):

```bash
FOO=foo date > $FOO.txt && echo "Wrote to $FOO.txt"
```

The problem is that $FOO gets expanded with the value of whatever FOO is when the command is parsed, not when it's executed. So if FOO is initially empty, that example will write to `.txt` and not `foo.txt`.

One solution is to use a subshell:

```bash
(FOO=foo; date > $FOO.txt && echo "Wrote to $FOO.txt")
```

That works fine. `FOO` is assigned inside the subshell and evaluated correctly where it's used.

What I don't get is why *this* doesn't work:

```bash
FOO=foo (date > $FOO.txt && echo "Wrote to $FOO.txt")
```

That's a ``` bash: syntax error near unexpected token ``(' ``` error.

How come that doesn't temporarily assign `FOO=foo` and then execute the subshell?

Comment: Note that it's not just subshells; it's *any* compound command.

Comment: I suspect it's to simplify the parser (which is already a gnarly mess of special cases). All compound commands begin with a fixed string of one sort or another: `(`, `((`, `[[`, `if`, `while`, etc. Anything that does *not* begin with one of that small set of strings is a simple command. If compound commands could start with precommand assignments, you would need an arbitrary amount of lookahead to decide what kind of command you were parsing.

Comment: You can use this work-around : `FOO=foo bash -c 'date > $FOO.txt && echo "Wrote to $FOO.txt"'`, which is equivalent of a subshell.

Comment: Note, too, that `FOO=foo date > $FOO.txt` does *not* write the current date to `foo.txt`, because `$FOO.txt` undergoes parameter expansion before the assignment `FOO=foo` takes effect.

Comment: When you define a `variable` right before the command in a single line in `bash` ( without using `;` between variable and command! ), that variable is passed to that process only not to the current shell session. In your case, you are trying to call the variable's value in your current shell, so the processes like `date` or `echo` which aren't intended to be impacted by such a variable like FOO are not impacted. Please test a Variable with a proper value for a process/command that is intended to use such variable, like: `TZ=PST date` or `TZ=UTC date`.

Comment: > "that variable is passed to that process only not to the current shell"

Exactly, so my question was - why can't you do that to pass a variable into a subshell, which is a separate process? I think @chepner was right - it's a syntactic limitation because bash's compound statement need to start with keyword.

Comment: Note that a subshell is not *necessarily* a subprocess; creating a new process is just a convenient way to separate the operating evironment. (If the subshell were in the same process, the shell would be responsible for keeping the two environments distinct.)